# How to compile and use FFMPEG library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

i'm newbie in Android Developing. I need use some video library to decompose my video. I have chose FFMPEG, and faced with a question - how integrate ffmpeg to my application and how to use it? I have Android Studio on Windows.

Comment: Which version of FFMPEG?

Comment: Any, but 3.0 e.g Can i use precompiled version of this lib?

Comment: Yes, you can use any prebuilt ffmpeg for Android. Cross-compiling ffmpeg on Windows is a torture, and Android Studio is of no help

Comment: @destroyer25t Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is this:

FFMPEG is a binary, and there are no nice, user-friendly libraries that mimick it's behaviour out there...

One attempt is this: https://github.com/RkShaRkz/android-ffmpeg (the avatar gives me away)

Another one is this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/files/20121012/

Alot of "solutions" revolve around either
1) launching the FFMPEG binary (process) and piping commands to it.
2) calling into FFMPEG libraries

But noone has yet made a nice FFMPEG-alike SDK library which lets you use everything it offers programatically in Java nor Android.

This was too long for a comment so thats why i posted it as an answer, i hope this doesn't get downvoted to oblivion for not providing a concrete answer/solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

i resolved it please follow this...

firstly go in File--->New-->Import module--> than Select FFMPEG Folder from your Computer.
after that it will be added in same hierarchy of your Project,
after again go into the File-->Project Structure-->app--> dependencies--> click on plus icon -->select 3).Module Dependencies Now in your list its been shown your Library select it

this solution is working for me
if not solved than please tell me i can help you if possible

Comment: @user4582544 please share the FFMPEG library?